# Where should I place my functions that wrap Doctrine queries?

Tags: symfony1, coding-style, doctrine

I'm learning Symfony + Doctrine 1.2 by writing a web app.  As the app grows in size, I would like to know where I should place my functions that wrap commonly used queries.  Is it good practice to create a custom library class and place all the functions there?  Currently, I have been placing the functions inside the Table class that Doctrine generates.

For example:

- getAllMessagesByUserId($userId) is a function in the MessageTable class.
- getOnlineUsers() is a function in the UserTable class.

Personally, I would prefer to have all the queries in one place, but I'm concerned that I would be breaking a "best-practice" rule.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be exactly where you have them... on the table classes for the models they query.

Comment: Good to know I was on the right track.  What do you suggest for queries that query multiple models?

Comment: @traveling coder: Put them in the table class of the primary model youre querying. By primary i mean what type of record/collection do you expect to get returned. For example if you expect the method to return an instance of User or a collection of Users then the method belongs on UserTable.